# replace all rows by rule

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have the table with varchar.
it contains values

```
a111
a112
a113
...
```

I want to repplce it like

```
b111
b112
b113
...
```

please help with update query

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Use `UPDATE` and string functions to convert the strings.

Comment: And never ask SQL questions without tagging your DBMS. SQL dialects differ (for example when it comes to string manipulation), so what works in MySQL for instance may not work in SQL Server etc.

Comment: Write an update query and show it to us. What problem are you having?

Comment: You mean to replace all values of "a" with "b"? Or you just want to replace the value of the first character in the string?  Is the first character in the string getting replaced for all records or only records starting with "a"?  What database are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, etc...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.xxx SET Value = REPLACE(Value, 'a', 'b')
```

Hope this will help.